# How do I change – (endash) to | (vertical bar) in my browser?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, browser

In the browser tab info of my site I want to replace the dash with a vertical line.

So instead of Site Name - Site Tagline it would be Site Name | Site Tagline.  It would also be like that on category pages, for example right now it is Site Name - Site Category but I would like Site Name | Site Category.  I am using the Goodlife theme but I have added the header.php below.  Does anyone know how I could change this?

header.php

```html
<!doctype html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head>
 <meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=1">
 <link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
 <link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>">
 <?php wp_site_icon(); ?>
 <?php 
  $header_style = ot_get_option('header_style', 'style1');
  $general_boxed = (ot_get_option('general_boxed') == 'on' ? 'boxed' : '');
 ?>
 <?php 
  /* Always have wp_head() just before the closing </head>
   * tag of your theme, or you will break many plugins, which
   * generally use this hook to add elements to <head> such
   * as styles, scripts, and meta tags.
   */
  wp_head(); 
 ?>
</head>
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
<div id="wrapper" class="open">
 
 <!-- Start Mobile Menu -->
 <?php do_action( 'thb_mobile_menu' ); ?>
 <!-- End Mobile Menu -->
 
 <!-- Start Content Container -->
 <section id="content-container">
  <!-- Start Content Click Capture -->
  <div class="click-capture"></div>
  <!-- End Content Click Capture -->
  <?php
   get_template_part( 'inc/header/fixed' );
   get_template_part( 'inc/header/subheader' );
   get_template_part( 'inc/header/'.$header_style );
   get_template_part( 'inc/header/pageskin' );
  ?>
  
  <div role="main" class="<?php echo esc_attr($general_boxed); ?>">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](https://wploop.com/change-title-separator/) article, you need to add the following code inside *functions.php*:

```
function wploop_change_separator()
{
return '|';
}
add_filter('document_title_separator', 'wploop_change_separator');
```